# A viable function with a default argument

Tags: c++, overloading

The following example is given in `N4296::13.3.3 [over.match.best]`

```
namespace A 
{
    extern "C" void f(int = 5);
}

namespace B 
{
    extern "C" void f(int = 5);
}

using A::f;
using B::f;

void use() 
{
    f(3); // OK, default argument was not used for viability
    f(); // Error: found default argument twice
}
```

I tried to write something similar:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace A
{
    void foo(int a = 5){ std::cout << a << "1" << std::endl; }
}

namespace B
{
    void foo(int a = 5){ std::cout << a << std::endl; }
}

using A::foo;
using B::foo;

int main()
{ 
    foo(2); //Error 
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa7c4983183ff295)

But I got a compile-time error. Why does the Standard says that it's OK?

Comment: I like that in your profile you remember the exact date of beginning programming.

Comment: Previous example used `extern "C"`...

Comment: BTW, gcc and clang accept the first example.

Comment: You can't overload extern "C" functions, AFAIK. Those in the different namespaces are the same, they are both effectively in the global namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is the extern "C", which affects namespace membership of the function:

From http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/1997/N1138.pdf

> What remains is the definition of “same entity” with respect to ‘extern “C”’ language linkage? This is
>   addressed by 7.5¶6:
>
> “At most one function with a particular name can have C language linkage. Two
>   declarations for a function with C language linkage with the same function name
>   (ignoring the namespace names that qualify it) that appear in different namespace scopes
>   refer to the same function. Two declarations for an object with C language linkage with
>   the same name (ignoring the namespace names that qualify it) that appear in different
>   namespace scopes refer to the same object.”

Comment: Now if there was a reason why identical default-arguments cannot be collapsed too...

Comment: Either I don't understand what you mean, or it doesn't affect namespace membership and your quote doesn't suggest otherwise. The declarations are still part of whatever namespace they're declared in, `A` and `B` in the question. They merely refer to the same function. `namespace N { extern "C" void f(); } void g() { f(); }` would fail to compile, because `f` is only declared as a member of `N`.

Comment: @hvd So we can't even declare two or more extern "C" functions in the same TU. So, a compiler doesn't matter about this, it's a linker's concern.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv Yes, typically, ODR violations where the conflicting definitions are in the same translation unit do get reported by the compiler, but for practical reasons, in this case you can tell it's left to the linker.

Answer (score -2):

That's because the two functions are imported from their namespace, this means that the same function has 2 definitions, you can solve it like this:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace A
{
    void foo(int a = 5){ std::cout << a << "1" << std::endl; }
}

namespace B
{
    void foo(int a = 5){ std::cout << a << std::endl; }
}

int main()
{ 
    A::foo(2);
    B::foo(3);
}
```